# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.receiver.RabbitMQReceiver

Tags: apache-spark, rabbitmq

I'm trying a simple RabbitMQ Receiver which will connect to rabbit-mq and stream the data through spark streaming. Currently I'm just printing the received data.

Any help would be appreciated!

I have the issue posted in the github: https://github.com/Stratio/spark-rabbitmq/issues/110

Code:

```
package enterprise.messaging.ism.consumer;

import java.util.*;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaReceiverInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.*;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

import com.rabbitmq.client.QueueingConsumer.Delivery;

public final class ConsumerApplication extends SpringApplication {

private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());

public ConsumerApplication(Object... sources) {
    super(sources);
}

@Override
protected void afterRefresh(ConfigurableApplicationContext context, ApplicationArguments args) {
    super.afterRefresh(context, args);
    logBeans(context);
    try {
        streamEnterpriseMessage(context);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void logBeans(ApplicationContext context) {
    logger.debug("Application context beans:");
    List<String> beanNames = Arrays.asList(context.getBeanDefinitionNames());
    beanNames.sort((name1, name2) -> name1.compareTo(name2));
    beanNames.stream().forEach(beanName -> logger.debug(beanName));
}

public static void streamEnterpriseMessage(ApplicationContext context) throws InterruptedException{

    try {



        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.setAppName("Sample Rabbit MQ Receiver");
        conf.setMaster("spark://10.205.233.177:7077");


        JavaStreamingContext streamCtx = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(1000));


        Map<String, String>rabbitMqConParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        rabbitMqConParams.put("host", localhost);
        rabbitMqConParams.put("queueName", testQueue);



        Function<Delivery, String> messageHandler = new Function<Delivery, String>() {

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public String call(Delivery message) {
                return new String(message.getBody());
            }
        };




        JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> receiverStream = RabbitMQUtils.createJavaStream(streamCtx, String.class , rabbitMqConParams, messageHandler);
        //logger.info("Data Stream", receiverStream.toString());
        receiverStream.print();


        streamCtx.start();
        streamCtx.awaitTermination();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //logger.error("Could not log sample enterprise message", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

}
```

POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.stratio.receiver</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-rabbitmq</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

Stack trace of error:

```
Exception: org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.receiver.RabbitMQReceiver
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1283)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition.readObject(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:70)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2122)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:253)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.receiver.RabbitMQReceiver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1819)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1986)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1919)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1529)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:552)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1276)
```

Environment :

Spark : 2.02

Rabbit MQ : 3.6.10

Java : 1.8 (Release 131)

Comment: can you post the link?

Comment: @meatspace [link] (https://github.com/Stratio/spark-rabbitmq/issues/110)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark ClassNotFoundException when run on yarn-cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416388/spark-classnotfoundexception-when-run-on-yarn-cluster)

Comment: Yes this possible the same issue as @T.Gawęda said. Please post your spark-submit call in the question.

Comment: @T.Gawęda Nope there is no manual Spark submit and my dependencies are handled by maven.

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim There is no manual spark submit and my dependencies are handled by Maven. What I could make of the exception is either its a deserialization error or there is some internal version mismatch

Comment: Is it running in a cluster or in your local machine?

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim My Application is connecting to a remote Spark Cluster.

Comment: The problem is, if you build your app as a Fat Jar, or with maven. The container of the worker will not have the JAR of RabbitMQ. Please, add the --jars at your spark call. Even it is a Spark Submit or a Spark Shell. The maven build will not work.

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim Thanks it worked! few of the jars needed on Spark-rabbitmq were not available in the classpath.